# Wildfly/JBOSS and persistent Timer - job not starting when NEXT_RUN in past

Tags: java, timer, jboss, wildfly

In the multiple-wildfly environment, we've got the persistent timer (run every minute), where the data store is database type (Oracle). 
All seems to be working properly, JBOSS_EJB_TIMER is created during deployment and it is properly updated whenever one of server run the job.

The problem is when for some reason, NEXT_DATE in JBOSS_EJB_TIMER is set to a date in past (it occurs during "dirty" wildfly restart and when there were problems with database connection for some time) - when NEXT_DATE is in past, the job seems to be not starting at all. Another strange thing is, that despite job is not running and JBOSS_EJB_TIMER table is not updated, I can see that Timer object for this job change it's next run time.
Can someone please, point me to right direction of what I could do? The most brutal way would be to run another job (though, this one not need to be persistent and can be run on multiple nodes) which will check if a value in this column is not in past. It sounds terrible for me (scheduled job to check for another scheduled job...), but I can't think/find another solution. I hope I just overlooked something in Schedule annotation/wildfly setup and someone will point me to right direction.

Here are some details:

Class with job

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class TestSchedule {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSchedule.class);

  public static final String NAME = "TestScheduleNameYay";


  @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*", info = NAME)
  public void test() {

    logger.debug("Some test...");

  }

}
```

Here is the result of querying some columns in JBOSS_EJB_TIMER table (please, note NEXT_DATE is in past):

```
SELECT INITIAL_DATE, REPEAT_INTERVAL, NEXT_DATE, PREVIOUS_RUN, INFO, TIMER_STATE FROM JBOSS_EJB_TIMER;

,0,2017-06-07 14:22:00.000000,2017-07-06 14:06:51.935000,Az4ZRW1haWxTZW5kZXJTaW5nbGV0b25UaW1lcg==,ACTIVE
```

With date in past, job is not running, though, when I iterate over Timers (which I got from TimerService.getAllTimers()) I see mine timer with proper date (extract from logs):

```
id=de67db05-e8d6-40aa-92f8-5e938ffd5eb2 timedObjectId=test-ear.test-ejb.TestSchedule auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@c8ba408 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Jul 06 14:32:00 CEST 20
17 timerState=ACTIVE info=TestScheduleNameYay]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I have same problem too

Comment: Hey @xxlali. No, rather workaround. It appears that this problem is only for auto-created timers (that is, when you use Schedule notification). I change code, so timers are created programaticaly (that is, using TimerService) - it appears that timers created that way are not affected by this problem (they are properly updated once db connection come back and etc.). Also, in my case it was not that much work (it was just couple code lines + tests). Please, let me know if you need help on how to create timers programaticaly. Thanks!

Comment: hello @user1223183. thanks for the reply. I guess I will go with creating programaticaly too. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem (but with Postgres database) and went to `jboss_ejb_timer` table. One of the rows had `RETRY_TIMEOUT` in `timer_state` column and `next_date` in the past. I have manually fixed the row (to `ACTIVE` state and slightly future `next_date`) and the timer is firing, again.